# C# Own maked "thread.sleep"

Tags: c#

I try make own "`thread.sleep`" that not lag application and i use .net framework 4 but i have some problems with this.. first `for` doesnt stop and that millisecond is current millisecond... so sometimes its over 200 and some times lower Hope you understand. thread.sleep lags and await cant use in .net framework 4.

```
int Wait
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{
    Wait += DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    if (Wait >= 20)
    {

    }
    Wait = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: My shooting game bullet interval :P Flash + C# server

Comment: You *can* use `await` in .NET 4, by the way - so long as you have a C# 5 compiler and use the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package.

Comment: You can either wait synchronously with Thread.Sleep, or asynchronously as @JonSkeet suggested. I see no point of doing that yourself.

Comment: Use the Stopwatch class instead of DateTime.Now

Comment: I dont want something packages ;/

Comment: Your code appears to assume that a tight loop with a mere 20 iterations will take over 200 milliseconds.  That will usually not be the case.  Also, there is no guarantee at what particular millisecond you are starting your loop, so it's very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user3249998 why is Thread a "package" but DateTime isn't

Comment: @I3arnon: I suspect he's referring to my Microsoft.Bcl.Async suggestion. But I agree that there's no point in reinventing Thread.Sleep...

Comment: How does Thread.Sleep() "lag" your application? And what does even "lag" mean to you?

Comment: Some would argue that lag is the whole point to Thread.Sleep :) Thread.Sleep has a default resolution > 1 ms by default, but that can be changed, as has been discussed many times here on SO (look right -->).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a game, what you probably really want is not some kind of sleep, but a timer or a game loop.